# Steganography Help - another example

Tags: visual, steganography

This picture contains a hidden message.  I can’t figure it out.  I have been working on it daily for a month.  Any help will be so appreciated![image]

Source: [Scrapbook One Hundred Seven…](https://dalneitzel.com/2014/11/12/scrapbook-one-hundred-seven/) (Forrest Fenn's treasure hunt)

Comment: Source: [http://pacte-contre-hulot.info/?o=Scrapbook+One+Hundred+Seven++Thrill+Of+The+ChaseThrill](http://pacte-contre-hulot.info/?o=Scrapbook+One+Hundred+Seven++Thrill+Of+The+ChaseThrill)

Answer (score 3):

> I don't have an answer, but I was able to find what I assume to have been the original image by using Google's reverse image search:
>
>  [image: Original]
>
>
>  and by cropping and resizing the image and comparing it to the one you provided, I don't see a lot of meaningful differences that can't be attributed to resizing/jpeg artifacts/imperfect cropping:
>
>  [image: Overlay]
>
>  One area which does stand out is the addition of a black dot on the dog-eared corner of the bill, but I'm not sure what significance it could have, if any.
>
>  Sorry I couldn't help more, but maybe having the original image to reference could reveal something else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this image can be decoded alone. Because...

> [Here is a recently resurrected thread originally from 2015](http://www.chasechat.com/showthread.php?tid=3156) discussing one of the puzzles as set forth in **The Thrill of the Chase** by Forrest Fenn, of which this image seems to be an integral part. I can't say more without looking into the entire "hunt", but you would be better off starting there.

Comment: Added more context to the puzzle, with a source which is hopefully relevant